# MVC4 Cannot implicitly convert type model in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model, controller, type-conversion

I am trying to get some information from my database through a stored procedure and then transfer it from my controller to my view:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MostrarRecord(String Fecha)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Siga los pasos para completar el proceso...";
        retail2Entities cl = new retail2Entities();
        DateTime fechaBase = Convert.ToDateTime(Fecha);
        GetIndividualSensorRecord_Result Records = cl.GetIndividualSensorRecord(ViewBag.IDSENSOR, ViewBag.TIPOSENSOR, fechaBase);


        return View(Records);
    }
```

But during runtime, I get the next error
Cannot implicitly convert *type'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'DataRebuilder.Models.GetIndividualSensorRecord_Result'.*

How can i correctly achieve this?

Also if i place:

> var Records = cl.GetIndividualSensorRecord(ViewBag.IDSENSOR,
>   ViewBag.TIPOSENSOR, fechaBase);

This is my model:

```
namespace DataRebuilder.Models
{
using System;

public partial class GetIndividualSensorRecord_Result
{
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
    public decimal idSensor { get; set; }
    public bool enter { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C01 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C02 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C03 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C04 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C05 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C06 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C07 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C08 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C09 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C10 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C11 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C12 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C13 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C14 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C15 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C16 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C17 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C18 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C19 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C20 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C21 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C22 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C23 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> C00 { get; set; }
}}
```

This is in my context.cs

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<GetIndividualSensorRecord_Result> GetIndividualSensorRecord(Nullable<int> idsensor, Nullable<int> entrada, Nullable<System.DateTime> fech)
    {
        var idsensorParameter = idsensor.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("idsensor", idsensor) :
            new ObjectParameter("idsensor", typeof(int));

        var entradaParameter = entrada.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("entrada", entrada) :
            new ObjectParameter("entrada", typeof(int));

        var fechParameter = fech.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("fech", fech) :
            new ObjectParameter("fech", typeof(System.DateTime));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetIndividualSensorRecord_Result>("GetIndividualSensorRecord", idsensorParameter, entradaParameter, fechParameter);
    }
```

I CAN transfer it, but how would I be able to explore the variable Records in the view? I.E. my model has 10 different strings that correspond.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried doing GetIndividualSensorRecord_Result Records = cl.GetIndividualSensorRecord(ViewBag.IDSENSOR, ViewBag.TIPOSENSOR, fechaBase).ToList(); ?

Comment: Yes, but the stored procedure provides only 1 row of data with different columns, it doesnt contains definition for ToList()

Comment: I believe the issue is that GetIndividualSensorRecord() returns an ObjectResult but you are trying to set it to the complex type GetIndividualSensorRecord_Result. Try doing a .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked with FirstOrDefault()... the main problem was my misuse of the ViewBag when invoking the stored procedure!

Comment: Good! I will put that comment as the answer for future searchers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that GetIndividualSensorRecord() returns an ObjectResult but you are trying to set it to the complex type GetIndividualSensorRecord_Result. Try doing a .FirstOrDefault()